# Split very big xml file into little pieces with specific line number count

Tags: cut, xml, split, head

This is how I did to extract the first 100000 lines from my big xml file (2gb):

```
head source.xml -n 100000 > part.xml
```

How can I keep splitting them to 100000 line (or specific file size chunks) until the whole file is separated?

Comment: you want this file to split in multiple files of `100000` lines right??

Comment: @Hackaholic Yes, 100000 is random number but I would like to limit the file size by line numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
split -l lines_per_file --additional-suffix=.xml source.xml part
```

This will read the file `source.xml` and split it into chunks of `lines_per_file` lines each. The result will be written into a series of files `partaa.xml`, `partab.xml`, `partac.xml`, ...

If you want to use another number of suffix characters, you can use the `-a` option to specify a number, eg. `-a 1` to name the files `parta.xml`, `partb.xml`, `partc.xml`, ...

If you want to split to file size chunks instead of line counts, you can use `-b size_in_bytes` instead of `-l lines_per_file`.

Please note that the resulting files will most likely be invalid XML files (unless you happen to get one file in return, ie. your input had too few lines/bytes to get split).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed and it did it very fast.

And yes, I'm aware that it will break the files in random places and will result invalid xml.